# Triple booting Windows 10, Ubuntu 15.10 and Remix OS Alpha

Tags: dual-boot, 15.10, windows-10, toshiba-satellite

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 and I dual boot it with Windows 10, but I would also like to install Remix OS Alpha along with it. It seems that Ubuntu doesn't let me select a boot device when I press escape on boot. Can anyone help?

Running on Toshiba Satellite C55-B5101

Comment: When I was first installing Ubuntu, when my computer was stock windows 10, escape brought me to a menu where I could select boot device.

Comment: I have used many Toshiba laptops and do not ever remember being able to access the boot menu by using the ESC key. Did you try F12, F1, or F10 yet?

Comment: Repeatedly pressing f12 did work for me, but it lists my USB drive as "Sandisk Cruzer" instead of REMIX, which is what I named it. Also, when I boot it, it just goes into the default ubuntu boot menu.

Comment: What boot manager do you use?

Comment: I don't know... for Ubuntu or Windows 10?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't successfully create a bootable device. What tool did you use to convert the iso to the USB device, universal pendrive linux, unetbootin?

Comment: I used the .exe usb tool that was in the .zip with Remix OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't install RemixOS to your hard drive you can only boot to it through your USB flash drive, your flash drive must be USB 3.0 and as you mentioned above it seems like you went to the boot menu and booted into your flash drive "Sandisk Cruzer", it's not called RemixOS because the name of your flash drive is that(Sandisk Cruzer), the reason your PC booted into Ubuntu is because you didn't install RemixOS properly on the flash drive. Install RemixOS on your flash drive and try again.

Answer (score 0):

On a Toshiba Satellite, immediately start tapping <kbd>F12</kbd> as soon as you start the computer to enter the boot menu.

For Toshiba Satellite laptops, press <kbd>F2</kbd> for setup and <kbd>F12</kbd> for the boot menu.

<kbd>esc</kbd> is for ASUS, HP, and other computers.

[source](http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Windows-8-8-1-Knowledge-Base/How-To-Accessing-the-Boot-Menu-on-a-Windows-8-computer/ta-p/346858)

Answer (score 0):

Try the function keys, especially F12, F8 and F2 on bootup.

You could also go into "advanced settings" (or something similar- usually the third or fourth option) in the GRUB menu. This should give the option of accessing BIOS settings. Then change the default boot device.